# Logs are not getting generated after adding APPIUM dependency

Tags: java, appium, qaf

I am trying to setup the QAF. Earlier when I set up the framework, I could see driver logs in console and output log file. But now I'm not seeing them. I did not make any change in log file configuration or it's directory. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Also I'm seeing below error in console

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.10.0
>
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem. Adding answer In case someone else comes across the same issue.

Added one more dependency now to resolve it.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>         
  <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
```